# NodeJS - How do i make a command that will run after a command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I wanted to make a command that will run after a command is called
Here's my code:

```
ownerID = "12042";
    if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix+"afk on")) {
      afk = true;
      if (afk == true) {
      message.channel.send("Turned on AFK mode");
        if (message.content.includes(config.ownerID)) {
            message.reply(`X is away. Try again later.`);
          }
        }
    }
    if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix+"afk off")) {
      afk = false;
      if (afk == false) {
      message.channel.send("Turned off AFK mode");
      }
    }
```

I tried to make an "AFK mode" command here, and if i send `afk on` it will reply `X is away` whenever someone typed `12042`.

Using that code, i get no answer at all, but if i make it

```
if (message.content.includes(config.ownerID)) {
    message.reply(`X is away. Try again later.`);
    }
```

it will reply without problems, but it will always reply as we all know

Comment: In your top-level if statements, you assign variables to their respective values and immediately check for that value. You dont need assignments here since you know your expression is a true and has no alternate execution flow. Also, why are you using strings instead of booleans?

Comment: @NoMoreQuestions Ahh it's actually booleans at my code, since im new to stackoverflow, kinda confused while posting this so i re-make the code. May i ask how should the code looks like?

Comment: Is this the entire contents of your `message` event handler? What's the scope of `afk`?

Comment: Where exactly is the issue you having in your first block? What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @AuxTaco this isn't entire contents, i only wanted to make the bot run `if (message.content.includes(config.ownerID)) {
    message.reply("X is away. Try again later.");
    }` only if i ran `afk on` and it won't run if i ran `afk off`

Comment: @NoMoreQuestions my expected output should be everytime i run `afk on` the bot will answered `X is away.` -->whenever<-- someone is mentioning this `ownerID`.

Comment: `message.content.includes(config.ownerID)` here means if someone mention ownerID, bot will reply `X is away`, but i want the bot do it whenever i typed `afk on` (i mean, bot **will start** it after i typed afk on). Like if i doesn't run `afk on` the bot won't reply `X is away` whenever someone mentioned ownerID. It will say it after i say `afk on`, and will keep saying that whenever someone mention ownerID

Comment: Are you sure your `message.content` is of the correct format, does it have `config.prefix`+`afk on`, or are you just sending `afk on`? Switch `message.content.startsWith` to `message.content.includes` to check.

Comment: @NoMoreQuestions Yes, it's from discord.js package, and my prefix in config.json is " , " so i actually run it using `,afk on` but i typed here `afk on` only instead to make it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of messages your bot should be looking for: `<prefix>afk on`, `<prefix>afk off`, and anything including `12042`. Your code only deals with `<prefix>afk on` and `<prefix>afk off`, with `12042` as a special case of the 'on' message. (If you try sending `<prefix>afk on 12042`, you should see your away message.) Restructure your code to check all three cases. The simplest (but not necessarily best) way would be something like

```
if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix+"afk on")) {
  // turn on afk mode
} else if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix+"afk off")) {
  // turn off afk mode
} else if (message.content.includes(config.ownerID)) {
  // send the afk message if afk mode is on
}
```

Comment: If `message.content.includes(config.ownerID)` is outside from `message.content.startsWith(config.prefix+"afk on")`, the bot will always send afk message everytime ownerID is mentioned, thats why i was making it `if (afk == true)` but it's not working

Comment: Note the comment in that branch: send the afk message _if afk mode is on_. You can implement that as a secondary check inside the `ownerID` branch or by changing the condition to `afk && message.content.includes(config.ownerID)`. Either way, it has nothing to do with the `afk on` branch.

Comment: I'm using `afk && message.content....` and now the bot keep replying whenever i mentioned ownerID, i don't know why, i've made `afk = true;` and `afk = false` and added `if (afk=true && message.content.includes....` on it.

Comment: That last snippet has exactly the wrong number of equals signs in it. Zero or three, not one. But are you sure `afk` has what you think it has? It needs to be defined outside of this handler if it's going to keep track of the afk mode between messages.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but this is my guess. The 'var afk' doesn't change it value into `true`, nor `false`. Thatas why the bot keep answering even though i run `afk off`

Comment: Without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), guessing is all we can do. Post code that can be copied and run directly from Node (redacting your discord token, of course).

Comment: aight, was about to do it. I'll make one

Comment: It's working, i tried to edit some lines, and then it's all good now! Thank's for the help :)